# If I enter a new registration number delete button should be disabled in C# windows form application

Tags: c#, windows, forms, button

If I enter a new registration number delete button should be disabled in C# windows form application Visual studio.
Form is student enrollment Registration form

Comment: That's not a question, I am afraid. Before it gets severely downvoted and closed, please consider [ask], maybe take the [tour] and improve it, so we actually _can_ help.  And welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the delete button on form load and on change of textbox check the registration number in your database whether the registration number is available if available then delete button will be active else delete button will be disabled.

- Always disable the delete button if the registration number is modified in your form.
- It will be active only if the registration number is found in your database.

Comment: I'd argue that a _new_ registration number (which seems to be some kind of unique identifier) should never be manually entered but system-generated. That said, a UX/UI redesign may be needed.

Comment: Yeah. I want the coding for that one only